# How to run several gulp functions sequentially?

Tags: javascript, gulp

To register a gulp task I use the following code:

```
gulp.task('test-module', function() {
    return testModule(__dirname);
});
```

This is `testModule` function :

```
export function testModule(modulePath) {
    let task1 = buildModule(modulePath, true);
    let task2 = buildTestModule(modulePath);
    let task3 = runModuleTests(modulePath);
    return [task1, task2, task1];
}
```

The problem with this code is that `runModuleTests(modulePath)` is called BEFORE `buildModule(modulePath, true)` and `buildTestModule(modulePath)` generate files. So, when `runModuleTests(modulePath)` is executed there are no files for testing and no files with tests.

I tried also

```
import gulpall from 'gulp-all';

export function testModule(modulePath) {
    return gulpall(
            buildModule(modulePath, true),
            buildTestModule(modulePath),
            runModuleTests(modulePath)
    );
}
```

but the result is the same. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your functions, especially the `buildModule` and `buildTestModule` are doing something asynchronous inside them.  So `runModuleTests` is called before they finish as you know.  I've simulated this behavior with the code below:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

// gulp.task('test-module', function() {
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return testModule(__dirname);
});

function testModule(modulePath) {
  let task1 = buildModule(modulePath, true);
  let task2 = buildTestModule(modulePath);
  let task3 = runModuleTests(modulePath);
  return [task1, task2, task1];
}

function buildModule (path)  {

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("in buildModule, should be step 1");
  }, 2000);
};

function buildTestModule (path)  {

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("in buildTestModule, should be step 2");
    }, 2000);
};

function runModuleTests (path)  {

  console.log("in runModuleTests, should be step 3");
};
```

I've put in delays in the first two functions to show what is happening when the earlier functions are asynchronous.  The result:

```
in runModuleTests, should be step 3
in buildModule, should be step 1
in buildTestModule, , should be step 2
```

One way to fix this is to use async/await and promises if you can.  so try this code:

```
gulp.task('test-module', function(done) {
    testModule(__dirname);
    done();
});

// function testModule(modulePath) {

async function testModule(modulePath) {

  let task1 = await buildModule(modulePath, true);
  let task2 = await buildTestModule(modulePath);
  let task3 = await runModuleTests(modulePath);

  return [task1, task2, task1];
}

function buildModule (path)  {
  return new Promise(resolve => {

    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(console.log("in buildModule, should be step 1"));
    }, 2000);

    // put your functionality here without the setTimeout() call above
  });
};

function buildTestModule (path)  {
  return new Promise(resolve => {

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(console.log("in buildTestModule, , should be step 2"));
    }, 2000);

    // put your functionality here without the setTimeout() call above
  });
};

function runModuleTests (path)  {
  return new Promise(resolve => {

   // put your gulp.src pipeline here
   console.log("in runModuleTests, should be step 3");
 });
};
```

Results:

```
in buildModule, should be step 1
in buildTestModule, , should be step 2
in runModuleTests, should be step 3
```

So make your functions return Promises and then await their result.  This will guarantee that the functions return in the right order.

Comment: Can you say, if this is the same : `let task1 = await new Promise(resolve => {
        buildModule(modulePath, true);
    });...`?

Comment: Your version doesn't work for me - gulp doesn't see that buildModule as finishing.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful and accurate don't forget to mark it as accepted.  Thank you.

Comment: What you right is very interesting but it is not a good solution for me. That's why I am waiting - maybe someone can suggest what will suit me better.

Answer (score 0):

In your gulp task method you can have a second argument where you define the task dependencies, that means that the dependencies are run before your main task.

Example:

```
gulp.task('after', ['before1', 'before2', ...], function() {

});
```

Comment: As I understand, your answer totally change the logic of my question. I don't need to create another tasks. I want to have only one task with multiple functions.

Comment: If you wrote the functions correctly, you dont need to change the logic, just add a wrapper arround the functions to create a gulp task.

Comment: What you suggest is what I don't want to do, as I said in the previous comment.

Comment: Note, that the question is about `running several gulp task functions sequentially` but not about `running several gulp task sequentially`.